# Fourier Transform based imputation

Tags: estimation, matlab, matrix, fourier-transform

[Fourier Transform based imputation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046415002269)

Can any body please assist me in understanding the Fourier Transform based imputation algorithm shown in Figure.

I am struggling to understand ts and te.[image: FT based imputation]

Link of the research paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046415002269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might come late, but I leave it here, just in case anybody lands here in the future.

$t_s = min(j)$ where $v_j$ is missing ==> this is the first position where a missing value is encountered

$t_e = min(j)$ where $v_j$ in non-missing ==> this is the first position after $t_s$ where a value (non-missing) is encountered

By detecting first $t_s$ and $t_e$, you have a "chunk" (sub-series) of values (till position $t_s$) followed by one or more missing values (till position $t_e$). The logic further uses DTF on the first $t_s$ values, padds it with zeros, performs IDFT and then replaces in the original vector the missing part. This is repeated until no missing values are left in the vector.

For example:

- You start with a vector like below (V = value, M = missing, I = imputed)

VVVVMMVVMMM

- you take the first 4 values, perform DFT, pad this result with 2 zero's, perform IDFT and replace the 2 M values with the ones from IDFT. you get:

VVVVIIVVMMM

- you take the first 8 values, perform DFT, pad this result with 3 zero's, perform IDFT and replace the 3 M values with the ones from IDFT. you get:

VVVVIIVVIII

- you stop because all values have been imputed.

The code in matlab is shared by the authors of the paper on github:
https://github.com/kleinberg-lab/FLK-NN

Comment: What is the intuition behind the logic that M values are replaced with ones from IDFT? Why those IDFT values are perfect to be replaced with Ms?

Comment: I do not understand the intuition behind the whole algorithm, specifically I do not understand why padding with zeros at the end of the dft. It is probably some type of interpolation, but as far as I understood in signal processing it is more common to add zeros in the middle of the dft rather than at the end.

Comment: in my case, a last-observation-carried-forward imputation gave better results than this "fourier based imputation". Also, the fourier based imputation gave better results on a rescaled or normalized time series, but still not as good as LOCF. I think this imputation might work best if you have a cyclic time series. In the case of the paper, the authors used lab data like glucose which is cyclic (though if I recall correctly, on their dataset LOCF was also giving better or comparable results)